# ggplot - annotate() - "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I ve read many SO Answers regarding what can cause the error "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale" but I still fail to solve the following issue. In my case, the error is caused by using `annotate()`. If get rid of  `+ annotate(...)` everything works well. Else the error is raised.

My code is as follows:

```
base <- ggplot() + 
     annotate(geom = "rect", ymin = -Inf , ymax = 0, xmax = 0, xmin = Inf, alpha = .1)
annotated <- base + 
     geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA, data = technicalsHt, aes(x = name, y = px_last))
> base  # fine
> annotated
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

Unfortunately, I cannot give the code leading to the dataframe used here (viz. `technicalsHt`) bacause it is very long and reliant on APis. A description of it:

```
> str(technicalsHt)
'data.frame':   512 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ date   : Date, format: "2016-11-14" "2016-11-15" ...
 $ px_last: num  1.096 0.365 -0.067 0.796 0.281 ...
 $ name   : Factor w/ 4 levels "Stock Price Strength",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

> head(technicalsHt)
        date     px_last                 name
1 2016-11-14  1.09582090 Stock Price Strength
2 2016-11-15  0.36458685 Stock Price Strength
3 2016-11-16 -0.06696111 Stock Price Strength
4 2016-11-17  0.79613481 Stock Price Strength
5 2016-11-18  0.28067475 Stock Price Strength
6 2016-11-21  1.10780834 Stock Price Strength
```

The code without `annotate` works perfectly:

```
    base <- ggplot() 
    annotated <- annotated + 
      geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA, data = technicalsHt, aes(x = name, y = px_last))
    > annotated   # fine
```

I tried playing around with `technicalsHt`, e.g. doing the following:

```
technicalsHt[,3] <- "hi"
technicalsHt[,2] <- rnorm(ncol(technicalsHt), 2,3)
```

but no matter what, using a `annotate` statement raises the error.

**EDIT:** 
following the answer below, I tried to put the `data` and `aes` in the initial `ggplot` call, and have `geom_boxplot` from the outset:

```
base <-                                  
# also tried: base <- ggplot(data = technicalsHt, aes(x = factor(name), y = px_last)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA)
annotated <- base + ggplot(data = technicalsHt, aes(x = name, y = px_last)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA)
  annotate(geom = "rect", ymin = -Inf , ymax = 0, xmax = 0, xmin = Inf, alpha = .1)
```

**this works but it is not really satisfactory since the annotation layer (shading part of the coordinate system) then covers the boxes.**

(While e.g., [that link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/yn34yeNJN7M) also mentions this error in connection with `annotate`, the answer given there does not solve my issue, so I would be extremely grateful for help. First of all, which of the variable is causing problem?)

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue and did not find the answer I wanted, so here is my solution. This is a bit prettier than plotting two times the boxplot.

If you want to annotate a rectangle below the points when there is a discrete scale you need to specify that to ggplot

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
  scale_x_discrete() +
  annotate(geom = "rect", ymin = -Inf , ymax = 10, xmax = 0, xmin = Inf, alpha = .1) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - very quick and easy solution.

Answer (score 6):

Switch around the order, and bring the data and main aesthetics into your `ggplot` call. You are basically writing this:

```
p1 <- ggplot() +
  annotate(geom = "rect", ymin = -Inf , ymax = 10, xmax = 0, xmin = Inf, alpha = .1)
```

At this point, `p1` has a continuous x axis, since you provided numbers here.

```
p2 <- p1 + geom_boxplot(aes(factor(cyl), mpg), mtcars)
```

Now you add another layer that has a discrete axis, this yields an error.

If you write it the 'proper' way, everything is OK:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  annotate(geom = "rect", ymin = -Inf , ymax = 10, xmax = 0, xmin = Inf, alpha = .1)
```

*p.s.*: Also it's not that hard to make a reproducible minimal example that accurately shows your problem, as you can see.

Comment: Thank you for this response @Axeman, I tried implementing things this way (see EDIT) but still get the error unfortunately.

Comment: First add the boxplot, then annotate?

Comment: Thank you @Axeman. Indeed this solution works but... the annotation (here a shading of part of the coordinate system) is then superposed to the boxes... as the layers sequentially superpose...

Answer (score 2):

In response to the layering, the easiest work around that i have found is simply plotting the same box plot twice. I am aware that it is unnecessary code, but it is a very quick fix for the layering issue.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  annotate(geom = "rect", ymin = -Inf , ymax = 10, xmax = 0, xmin = Inf, alpha = .1) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

I cannot notice any image degradation from it as the pixels perfectly overlap. Feel free to correct me if anyone has a UHD monitor.